# Netty decoder result - send proper response codes for bad request

Tags: java, http, exception, netty, http-status-codes

I'm looking at the HttpStaticFileServerHandler example at [Netty Github](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/file/HttpStaticFileServerHandler.java). On messageRecieved, if the decoder result is not success, bad request is thrown. So the response code goes as 400. I would like to send 414 when the request uri is too long.

I've tried,

```
Throwable cause = requestMessage.getDecoderResult().cause();
String message = cause != null ? cause.getMessage() : "";
HttpResponseStatus responseStatus = cause instanceof TooLongFrameException?
      HttpResponseStatus.REQUEST_URI_TOO_LONG : HttpResponseStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
```

Is there a better way? I believe TooLongFrameException is thrown for other cases as well. So in those cases it may not be right. Parsing the error message also doesn't look good. Wondering if this can be done in a better/elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

A bit further down in that handler is the code block:

```
    final String uri = request.uri();
    final String path = sanitizeUri(uri);
    if (path == null) {
        sendError(ctx, FORBIDDEN);
        return;
    }
```

Could you use this block with a uri.length() check and relevant sendError?